# Woocommerce list prouct attribute type values

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would like to list in php all values of all attributes. I used the wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() function to list all my attributes. It's ok, but I would like to list its registered values in wp dashboard. For example I got this:

```
'id:6' => object(stdClass)[10735]
      public 'attribute_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'attribute_name' => string 'meats' (length=5)
      public 'attribute_label' => string 'Meats' (length=6)
      public 'attribute_type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      public 'attribute_orderby' => string 'menu_order' (length=10)
      public 'attribute_public' => int 0
```

I would like to access to values of attribute_type. How can I list it?

Thank you!